# Apply CSS for One Cateory (and it's sub-categories)

Tags: woocommerce

Ultimately, I want to hide or disable Related Products for one category (and it's children).  I have the following code, but it's not working and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
function hideRelated () {
    if ( is_product_category(18) ) {
        ?>
  <style>
    .woocommerce .related.products { display: none; }
  </style>
  <?php
    }
}
add_filter('wp_head', 'hideRelated');
```

Comment: First of all, `is_product_category` expects you to pass the category **slug** not the category id. [REFERENCE](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/acbe200c79815deda60e9fd5cc1aa63fccdda070/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-conditional-functions.php#L50-L61). Second, which page are you trying to run this on? On `category archive` page? On `single product` page? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I'll use the slug.  I want this to run on the single product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone else - the below code worked for me:

```
// add taxonomy term to body_class
function woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
if( is_singular( 'product' ) )
{
$custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
if ($custom_terms) {
foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
$classes[] = 'product_cat_' . $custom_term->slug;
}
}
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

This adds the product category slug as a body class - which can then be called in CSS.